# Combining query results

Tags: union

Is it at all possible to combine two different query results into one feed of results?

I have two types of content in my site, one is based upon a wordpress network and brings in 
Link to post,
Title,
Blog Name,
Image (generated from blog post content),
Date.

the other is a set of user added music links and brings in
Link to music,
Name of music,
Name of artist,
Image (path of uploaded image saved to database),
Date.
List of genres tags (a serialised array)

I tried a union, however despite how these columns all generate the same category of content, the actual contents and therefore how they are output is completely different.

What can I do to combine all of these? Is there a way to figure out which table they are currently from from the union query? Then I could use an if statement to decide how to output the contents.

Comment: Yes, anything is possible, but you've told us nothing about what you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a UNION you would be able to add in a extra field which is the 'type' (i.e. 0 = Blog, 1 = Music, etc.)

Then on the front end of the application retrieve data from that field and then use that to decide what type it actually is / which elements to include.

Comment: Would I be able to add that in generated by the query or would that have to be added into the original tables already?

Comment: You can add it into the query you use.  `SELECT 1 AS Type, * FROM table1 UNION SELECT 2 AS Type, * FROM table2`